# Application working on http but not on https

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

**Background**: I have two backend instances running haproxy, apache, nodejs on ports 4000 and 8007 for haproxy, 80 for httpd, 3000 3007 3012 running node. I have a staging site which is running on this instance. I have signed certificate installed at ELB level and ELB listening on https 443 port to backend http 80 port.

**Issue**: When I tried to login to the stating url with http then the backend is working fine on port 80 and 3000, network flow logs also returning status code as Ok for request to **http**://stating _url:3000. But when I tried to access site on https then I am getting status as "**blocked:mixed-content**" for **https**://stating _url:3000 request. Please refer to below screenshots

Below is output for http which is working as expected

[image: accessing url on http and all good]

Below is the output for https which is not working as expected

[image]

I tried different protocols for listeners at ELB level. I dont understand why ELB on port 80 sends request to port 80 on backend server and all works fine but same ELB on port 443 sends request to same port 80 on backend server but fails to establish connection with 3000.

Comment: You need to load all resources over HTTPS.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. how could I do that. my backend instance has 80 port listening and I am directing the request from ELB 443 to backend port 80.

Comment: Find the resource URLs that don't use HTTPS and make them use HTTPS.  What don't you understand?

Comment: yes,  I already did that, but still facing the same issue. I replaced http with https for those resources but it didnt work. Check the second screenshot which shows https resource not returning the ok status code as of http resource in first screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show anything useful.

Comment: I have masked the url name in the screenshot, but yes changing the resource to https didnt work.

Comment: You haven't shown an error or anything else helpful.